# Mongod is not a service | Ubuntu | WSL. Error: mongod: unrecognized service

Tags: linux, mongodb, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I tried setting up mongodb. There are two issues:

1. Running the command `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` results in the error below.

   Errors were encountered while processing:
   /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-NtCqHi/1-mongodb-org-server_4.4.4_amd64.deb
   /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-NtCqHi/2-mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.4_amd64.deb
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
2. Although the command `mongod --version` results in:

   db version v3.6.8
   git version: 8e540c0b6db93ce994cc548f000900bdc740f80a
   OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
   allocator: tcmalloc
   modules: none
   build environment:
   distarch: x86_64
   target_arch: x86_64
   which is not the latest, even though I installed the latest community version.
   running `sudo service mongod start` shows the following error:

   mongod: unrecognized service

the list of available services currently in the system are:

```
sudo service --status-all

 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ - ]  atd
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ - ]  cron
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ - ]  iscsid
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ - ]  multipath-tools
 [ + ]  open-iscsi
 [ - ]  open-vm-tools
 [ ? ]  plymouth
 [ ? ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  postgresql
 [ - ]  procps
 [ + ]  redis-server
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  screen-cleanup
 [ - ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sysstat
 [ - ]  udev
 [ - ]  ufw
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```bash
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mongodb

sudo service mongodb start
```

**My setup**: win10, wsl2